# How can I permanently store user inputs automatically into the dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, authentication, module

```
users = {
    "Hi":"HM123",
    "alan": "12122",
    "12": "11"
}
def adder():
    new_user = input("Please enter user's name: ").strip()
    new_pwd = ""
    confirmer = "0"
    while new_pwd != confirmer:
        new_pwd = input("please enter a new Password: ").strip()
        confirmer = input("please confirm your password: ").strip()
        if new_pwd != confirmer:
            print("passwords does not match!!")
    users[new_user] = new_pwd
adder()
```

I used The dictionary as a collection of usernames and passwords to practice creating a simple functional login page.(i'm importing this as a module to my main file). and when I add new users and passwords this code above temporarily adds it to the dictionary but when I re-run the script and try the new user names and pwds it returns incorect username and password, bc they are not in the dictionary.

was hoping to find a way to add the new usernames and paswwords into the dictionary permanently just with user inputs without having to modify the dictionary my self.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your dictionary (more or less) is stored in RAM which is voilatile - you cannot (or at least, you shouldn't try to) preserve it between different scripts run.

Thas is why people use databases - they are stored on disk and don't vanish unless something really bad happens ;)

The easiest what would suits your needs is to store them in a single `json` file. It is a format very similar to python dictionary. Python has `json` library that allows it to parse such file into pythons `dict` and the opposite - put the `dict` back into the file.

Here is the example:

```
import json

with open("users.json", "r+") as f:
    # convert content of file users.json into users variable - it will be a dict
    users = json.load(f)

def store_to_file(users):
    with open("users.json", "w") as f:
        # save the users dict into the file users.json in json format
        json.dump(users, f, indent=4)

def adder():
    ...
    store_to_file(users)

adder()
```

Do not forget to create the file `users.json`!

```
{
    "Hi": "HM123",
    "alan": "12122",
    "12": "11"
}
```

Comment: you didn't mentionned `json` in your explanation

Comment: Thanks for a suggestion, I desribed it briefly.

Answer (score 1):

Python dictionaries can be converted to JSON text and written to permanent storage as such.

You could also consider serialisation of the dictionary using the *pickle* module.

Here's an example of both techniques:

```
import pickle
import json

PFILE = '/Volumes/G-Drive/users.pkl'
JFILE = '/Volumes/G-Drive/users.json'

users = {
    "Hi": "HM123",
    "alan": "12122",
    "12": "11"
}

with open(PFILE, 'wb') as db:
    pickle.dump(users, db) # save the dictionary (serialise)

with open(PFILE, 'rb') as db:
    _users = pickle.load(db) # retrieve serialised data
    print(_users)

with open(JFILE, 'w') as db:
    json.dump(users, db) # save as JSON

with open(JFILE) as db:
    _users = json.load(db) # retrieve JSON and convert to Python dictionary
    print(_users)
```

**Output:**

```
{'Hi': 'HM123', 'alan': '12122', '12': '11'}
{'Hi': 'HM123', 'alan': '12122', '12': '11'}
```